# ID cannot be specified for Azure Analysis Services role member

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-analysis-services

I am working on AAS Deployment via Azure Pipeline.

While deployment when it comes to add ID in roles, it fails saying

> "ID cannot be specified for Azure Analysis Services role member."

What ever email id, I am specifying under roles it fails for same error message. I am not sure how to add roles here. this role is for readonly access.

can anyone please help me on this? Either roles should be able to added here only or i guess there should be some other work around.

Comment: Are you able to deploy from visual studio solution ? Can you provide the YAML you are using to deploy ?